# Different responses IP and domain name

Tags: internet, troubleshooting

I have a domain name that is using a public IP, when I send two requests, one to the domain name and one to the IP I get different headers in each one, in one of them 4 cookies are set, in the other one only 2 are set. Using nslookup and some online tools, I can see the domain name is linked with the ip, so I'm finally testing the same thing (IP and domain name) but getting different responses. The public IP is translated into one private inside my LAN, the firewall that is making this does not insert anything. This is really weird.

What can be wrong?

Comment: You should put your request and answer to see what is different

Comment: Questions about protocols above OSI lauer-4 are explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a domain name that is using a public IP, when I send two requests, one to the domain name and one to the IP I get different headers in each one, in one of them 4 cookies are set, in the other one only 2 are set.

(...)

> What can be wrong?

Make sure your HTTP client is sending the same request for both cases.

Request line format: `Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF`

Exemple for request line: `GET http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1`

In example above, Request-URI is `http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/TheProject.html`

If your client puts an IP addresses in the place of the hostname `www.w3.org`, the web server might issue a different result.

See also: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html